# Firefox not sending data via ajax to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I'm trying to send data to my server as a `json` datatype via ajax. Currently in Firefox the server receives no data but in Chrome and IE the data is received and output on the server console.

This is my code:

```
$(function () { 
$(document).on('click', '.send', function(e) {
    var dataToSend = [];
    $('.form-group1').each(function () {
        var data = {};
        $(this).find(':input[data-name]').each(function () {
            data[$(this).data('name')] = $(this).val();
        });
        dataToSend.push(data);
    });

    $.ajax({
       url: '/pers1',
       type: 'POST',
       contentType:'application/json',
       data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
       dataType:'json'
     });        
       console.log(JSON.stringify(dataToSend))
  });
});
```

Why would Chrome and IE send this to the server but Firefox wouldn't?

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for errors, and to see if an HTTP request is being made?

Comment: Where are you printing the response in the console? The only thing I see you doing is printing what you are SENDING to the server.

Comment: @Pointy, yes no errors and shows a 200 OK response

Comment: @Antiga, on my server side code I print out the response to

Comment: @user94628 Alright. Just so I understand, you can see the call being made for sure in FF, but without any data going with it?

Comment: I suggest posting your form or setting up a demo in jsfiddle

Comment: So it *is* sending something to the server. Have you checked to see (again, in the developer console or FireBug) what the HTTP Request and Response headers look like?

Comment: In logging no http request is made to `/pers1` only `/pers` which sends as `method=post` the rest of the form data. The 'url' send the data to a server side `handler` `/pers1` which saves the data into the DB and redirects back to the url at `/pers`

Comment: Tip: Instead of nesting those 2 loops in the beginning of your code, you could use just `.serialize()`. http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0):

maybe a problem with data option instead of JSON.stringify, you could try to serialize the data of the form

```
$('form.my-form').serialize();
```

or if your inputs are not inside a form , you could do it with the container div

```
$('#divId input').serialize();
```